# Possible to have multiple Python except statements when using try (without searching for a specific except)?

Tags: python, django, try-catch

This is my current code:

```
def get_queryset(self)
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']

    try: 
        postD = PostD.objects.get(pk=pk)
        # In the line below, PostReply.objects.filter(postD=postD) is
        # not guaranteed to exist, so I am using a try statement.
        return PostReply.objects.filter(postD=postD)

    except:
        postY = PostY.objects.get(pk=pk)
        # In the line below, PostReply.objects.filter(postY=postY) is
        # not guaranteed to exist either, so this may raise an error.
        return PostReply.objects.filter(postY=postY)

    # Here, I want one last except statement to execute if the above try
    # and except statements fail... Is it okay to just add another except
    # statement like this:

    except:
        postR = PostR.objects.get(pk=pk)
        # If the above try and except statement fail, this is guaranteed to
        # not throw an error.
        return PostReply.objects.filter(postR=postR)
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
try:
    # code
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    # code
except:
    # last part of code
```

but it is not guaranteed that I will be getting an `ObjectDoesNotExist` error (I'm not guaranteed what error I will be getting). So I'm wondering if there is a way of having more than one except statement without specifying what exception to look for? Is the way I did it above (where I just have `try: except: except:` okay to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bare `except:` will catch anything and everything, so it makes no sense to have a second except block in this case.

Possibly you wanted to put the code inside your first `except` block into another nested try/except block.

*Note*: [Pokemon exception handling](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PokemonExceptionHandling) is considered bad coding style, and it's better if you only try to catch the actual exceptions which you intend to handle - in this case, only catching the `DoesNotExist` should be sufficient.

You might consider using a loop to refactor this:

```
PostModels = {
    'postD': PostD,
    'postY': PostY,
    'postR': PostR,    
}

for k,Post in PostModels.items():
    try: 
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        return PostReply.objects.filter(k=post)
else:
    # all 3 lookups failed, how do you want to handle this?
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the first `except` will catch any exception raised from the `try` block, the only way "the above try and except statements fail" is if code in the first `except` block raises an exception. To catch that, you should wrap it directly with `try/except`:

```
def get_queryset(self)
    try:
        ...
    except:
        try:
            <<original first except-block here>>>
        except:
            <<original second except-block here>>>
```

Also, in general you should avoid bare `except:`.